# Не работает функция двойного клика по кнопке

Tags: javascript, функции, button

У меня проблема подключить функцию двойного клика:

```
$btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('kick');
  changeHP(random(10), character);
  changeHP(random(10), enemy);
});

const doubleClickThreshold = 250;
console.log(doubleClickThreshold);
const clicker = document.getElementById('click');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function createClicker(clickFn, dblClickFn) {
  let timer;
  return function (event) {
    const context = this;

    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      dblClickFn.call(context, event);
      timer = null;
      return;
    }

    timer = setTimeout(function (ctx) {
      timer = null;
      clickFn.call(ctx, event);
    }, doubleClickThreshold, context)
  }
}

function onClick(event) {
  output.innerHTML = 'click';
}

function onDoubleClick(event) {
  output.innerHTML = 'double click';
}      

const clickHandler = createClicker(onClick, onDoubleClick);
clicker.onclick = clickHandler;
```

Comment: Опишите проблему подробнее

Comment: вторая функция для двойного клика не работает, а первый 'click' работает

Comment: может использовать нативный `dblclick`?

Comment: с dblclick не сработало, я же нашла что можно использовать счетчик для подсчета последнего клика, и функцию. Но не могу понять почему код не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что timer = null

```
timer = setTimeout(function (ctx) {
  timer = null;
  clickFn.call(ctx, event);
}, doubleClickThreshold, context)
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/512532)

Comment: Не согласен. Вопрос был в том, почему не работает код.
Ответ был дан. Не работает, потому как переменная timer зануляется в приведенном выше коде. И дальше где проверка на второй клик if (timer) = false не заходит в условие.

Comment: ну так добавьте подробные разъяснения в ответ. Если автор вопроса сам не понял, что дело в этой строке кода, скорее всего, ему необходимы некоторые пояснения, чтобы в полной мере разобраться в вопросе.